# PyPDF2 no extracting text properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, encoding, pypdf

My code can read in the PDF file but I can't extract the text with PyPDF2. It worked with other PDF files before. Why is the text appearing in this encoded form and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = pypdf.PdfFileReader(f)
    print(reader.getPage(1).extractText()) # get table of contents
```

Here's the output:

'"#$%&!#&'$#()!"*+!+%,'+#&!-\n!!"#$%&!\n.$#&%,+/,!'#$0#12\n!!3!(./01&23&42561567\n&!!"#$%&#'(")%(%*+,%-#(\n.(/!!0!\n!&12,3*4(\n,-15%6#\n(/!!0.\n!"#$%&#(\n+,#&%5%&37%1*\n(/!!0/\n!"#$%&#(\n+,#&%5%&37%1*(\n+18-&#\n(9!.!,:171;-3,:+\n(9!.0!\n!#<7#-%1-(\n,:171+\n(=!.0.\n!%*7#-%\n1-(\n,:171+\n(!!!.0/\n!&61+#\n>8,(\n,:171+\n(!?!/!"#$%&#(7#3-"1@*\n(.A!/0!\n!"-1*#\n(.A!/0.\n!&1*7-166#-\n(?.!B!&12,1*#*7(%"#*7%5%&3\n7%1*\n(9?!B0!\n!3%-&-357(\n23%*(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(9?!B0.\n!3%-&-357(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(9D!B0/\n!3%-&-357(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(=.!B0B\n!3%-&\n-357(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(=/!B0?\n!&1*7-166#-(\n23%*(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(=B!B09\n!&1*7-166#-(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(=9!B0=\n!&1*7-166#-(\n&%-&8%7(\nC13-"\n(=D!?!+367#"("373\n(E!!9!"373(3&F8%+%7%1*+\n(E!!90!\n!"373\n(3&F8%+%7%1*(\n2#7:1"+\n(E!!90.\n!"373(\n+71-3;#(\n61&37%1*+\n(E.!90/\n!"373(\n3&F8%+%7%1*+\n(E.!=!3""%7%1*36(-#+18-&#+\n(EB!=0!\n!&1,7#-+35#(\nG-8++%3*("-1*#(21"%5%&\n37%1*(C8+%*#++\nH(I(%*+,%-#(\n.(*5J\n(21"(EB!=0.\n!!"#$\n%&'()(%*&!+,'(%&-+(&\n./#0*&1,+&1#022-3(+%\n(EB!=0/\n!")%\n(%*+,%-#(\n.(7#3-"1@*\n'(@:37K+(%*+%"#\nL(E?!=0B\n!&618"(\n&%74(\n"-1*#+\n(E?!E!3,,#*"%<\n(E9!E0!\n!23*853&78-#-(+,#&%5%&\n37%1*(+:##7\n(E9!E0.\n!1@*#-\nK+(23*836\n(E9!E0/\n!F8%&M(\n+73-7(;8%"#\n(E9!E0B\n!+35#74(;8%"#6%*#+\n(E9!E0?\n!C377#-4(+35#74(;8%"#6\n%*#+\n(E9!E09\n!")%\n(%*+,%-#(\n.(%*>7:#\n>C1<(E9!'

Comment: PDF text is not the easiest to work with and the text which is read on the document often is not extracted properly. I'm guessing this is another of those cases.

Comment: So, it's near impossible to figure out how to decrypt this data and get the original text using Python?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: You might want to try Optical Character Recognition (OCR), here is an example [post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-contents-of-pdf-using-ocr-optical-character-recognition/). It might be an alternative.